# How to add vertical line to a bar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code :

```
ax = df30_pivoted.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(30,20), linewidth=5)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.tick_params(labelsize=20)
plt.xlabel('session_date', fontsize=20)
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('', fontdict={'fontsize':60})
legend = ax.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0,1,1), fancybox=True, shadow=False, title='variations', prop={'size':45})


xposition = c12
for xc in xposition:
    ax.axvline(x=xc, color='r', linewidth=4)
plt.setp(legend.get_title(), fontsize='30')

plt.show()
```

i expect above code put vertical line where index on x axis is equivalent to what i have in c12 , c12 is a pandas Series with type `datetime64[ns]` but resulted bar plot has no vertical line :

[image]

Comment: What is `c12`? You need to provide a [mcve] if you want help.

Comment: Can you iterate of c12?

Comment: Isn't your plot showing vertical lines?